# How do I edit the crontab of another user on my linux server?

Tags: linux, cron

I have a user on my linux server who has sudo.  I want to edit the crontab of another user.  I'm new to this though and don't understand what the man pages are telling me yet.

Man crontab tells me I can use this format for the crontab command:

```
crontab [ -u user ] { -l | -r [ -i ] | -e }
```

But what does that mean?  I want to edit the crontab of a user named jake

so I tried

```
crontab jake -e
crontab [jake] -e
crontab [-u jake] -e
```

And I get the same error every time: "usage error: no arguments permitted after this option"

So what do I type in to edit jake's crontab?

Comment: The `[ -u user ]` means that you can optionally say `-u user`. I would've expected to see `user` either in italics (when typeset) or as `<user>` to indicate that it's not the literal string "user" you need to give,

Answer (score 114):

Try

```
crontab -e -u jake
```

You will need to be `root` for this to work.

Comment: `sudo crontab -e -u jake` would work without being root, and gets logged.  Could also `su jake` and then do `crontab -e` but sudo much better.

Comment: @dunxd `su` doesn't work with disabled users or users without login shell. Like `www-data` is not a user you can switch to on many systems, yet this user has cronjobs to do.

Answer (score 0):

you need sudo/root to edit any of crontab

Comment: On many systems you can edit your own crontab without sudo/root.

Comment: @JennyD AFAIK if you have not add user entry in following file it wont work. # vi /etc/security/access.conf

Comment: There are many varieties of unix, and many flavours of linux. Blocking crontab from regular users does not happen in all of them.

Comment: How is this an answer? The OP already specified he has sudo.